# Xamarin.Forms SQLite ,initialize data once on table creation

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin and I am trying to make xamarin.form app which contains sqlite database. So I know that the table is created once but also I have some records that I need to be in that table by default. I mean when table is created the data also must be initialized with it once. According to tutorial I have a class to handle the database called `DataAccess.cs`

```
class DataAccess : IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            database.Dispose();
        }

        private SQLiteConnection database;
        public ObservableCollection<DataModel> dataz { get; set; }
        private static object collisionLock = new object();

        public DataAccess()
        {
            database = DependencyService.Get<IConfig>().DbConnection();
            database.CreateTable<DataModel>();

            //database.Insert(new DataModel { Did = 1 , Data = "aaaa"});
            //database.Insert(new DataModel { Did = 2, Data = "bbb" });
            //database.Insert(new DataModel { Did = 3, Data = "ccc" });

            this.dataz = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>(database.Table<DataModel>());



            if (!database.Table<DataModel>().Any())
            {
                addNewData();
            }

        }

        public void addNewData()
        {
            this.dataz.Add(new DataModel { Did = 1, Data = "aa" });
        }

        public void SaveData(DataModel record)
        {
            lock (collisionLock)
            {
                database.Insert(record);
            }
        }

        public DataModel GetDataById(int id)
        {
            lock (collisionLock)
            {
                return database.Table<DataModel>().
                  FirstOrDefault(x => x.Did == id);
            }
        }

        public List<DataModel> GeyAllData()
        {
            return database.Table<DataModel>().ToList();
        }



    }
```

Since the table is created in above class instructor. So I tried to initialized data there but data added to table on each run. So I confused how to initialize data on first run only.

Comment: Could just check for your seed data on run,  if there you don’t need to insert it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go one of two ways.

1: Check if the table does not exist yet and if not, create it and add your data

```
var result = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='DataModel';", new string[] { });
if (result == 0)
{
    await conn.CreateTableAsync<DataModel>();

    // Insert your initial data    
}
```

2: Always check if the data exists and insert it if it does not

FYI: Assuming `Did` is your PrimaryKey of `DataModel`

```
var row = await conn.FindAsync<Record>(1);
if (row == null)
{
   // Insert the "Did = 1" row
}
```

Comment: if (!database.Table<DataModel>().Any())
            {
                addNewData();
            } in this part i handle the same ..... since i came from sql server back ground still it is unusaul for me :|